# How to make this code more optimized in terms of time?

Tags: python, time-complexity, combinations, python-itertools

I have a written the code here but it is taking much time. I need to optimize it more. The k here varies, it can be 2 or 3 or 4, depends on the user. Please help me out here.

```
from itertools import combinations

def get_all_combinations(input_list, k):
    for item in combinations(input_list, k):
        yield list(set(list(item)))

input_list = [1, 2, 1, 2, 3]
k = 3
lst = []
for i in range(1, k + 1):
    for item in get_all_combinations(input_list, i):
        if len(item) > i - 1:
            lst.append(item)
print(len(lst))

>>17


#[[1], [2], [1], [2], [3], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 2], [2, 3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

```
 from itertools import combinations

def get_all_combinations(input_list,k):
    l = []
    for item in combinations(input_list, k):
        l.append( list(set(list(item))))
    return l

input_list = [1, 2, 1, 2, 3]
k = 3
lst = []
for i in range(1,k+1):
    gac = []
    gac = get_all_combinations(input_list, i)
    for item in gac:
        if len(item) > i-1:
            lst.append(item)
print(len(lst))
```

base on [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41671005/yield-slower-than-return-why)

Comment: I am sorry to waste your time... But I edited a small thing in the query code... Can you please look into it and help me with optimized solution... Thank you @ShahabRahnama

Comment: @Remus test it!

Answer (score 0):

With the following version your processing will go nearly **twice** as fast:

```
from itertools import combinations

def get_all_combinations(input_list, k):
    for i in range(1, k + 1):
        for item in combinations(input_list, i):
            s = set(item)
            if len(s) >= i:
                yield list(s)

input_list = [1, 2, 1, 2, 3]
k = 3
lst = list(get_all_combinations(input_list, k))
print(lst)
```

The output remains the same:

```
[[1], [2], [1], [2], [3], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 2], [2, 3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: I am sorry @RomanPerekhrest, to waste your time... But I edited a small thing in the query code... Can you please look into it and help me with optimized solution... Thank You

Comment: @Remus, my approach is still relevant - why don't you use it? what's is the issue?

Comment: I mean I now I can just do len(lst) in print but I think getting sequences in the list is using time somehow which might be relevant to O(n)... Can we use more verbal way, like using count or something like that?...

Comment: @Remus, the primary condition is covered and has answers. For new conditions - create new questions

Comment: I will that in mind... Thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```py
>>> input_list = [1, 2, 1, 2, 3]
>>> k = 3
>>> [list(set(el)) for i in range(1, k+1) for el in itertools.combinations(input_list, i) if len(set(el))>i-1]
[[1], [2], [1], [2], [3], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 2], [2, 3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: according to the OP's logic - each item needs to be a **set**

Comment: I am sorry to waste your time... But I edited a small thing in the query code... Can you please look into it and help me with optimized solution... Thank you @GrzegorzSkibinski

Answer (score 0):

If this is meant to be homework, your instructor is probably looking for this.

```
lst = [list(c) for i in range(k) for c in combinations(input_list, i+1) if len(set(c)) > i]
```